# Segfault when assigning token pointer (from strtok) to pointer element of 2d VLA of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-length-array

I'm attempting to parse a csv file and store those values in an 2d VLA.
The first codeblock shows the two calls I have to the function TokenizeLine which very simply uses strtok to break the line apart and assign the token to the appropriate cell in the array. The second block is the function in question.

```
  //Get first line of file then iterate through lines until
  //beginning comments are passed over
  fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn); 
  while (currentLineStr[0] == '#')
        fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn);

  //Start adding values to array. current line held by currentLineStr
  //is assigned first
  TokenizeLine(currentLineStr, eTable, yIndex, x, y);

  yIndex++;
  while(fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn) != NULL)
  {
        TokenizeLine(currentLineStr, eTable, yIndex, x, y);
        yIndex++;
  }
```

Within the following function I'm getting a segfault when assigning the token pointer to the pointer contained in the eTable struct.

```
void TokenizeLine(int x; int y; char currentLineStr[], Entry eTable[x][y], int yIndex, int x, int y)
{
  char *tokPtr;
  int xIndex = 0;

  tokPtr = strtok(currentLineStr, "|");
 *** eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str = tokPtr;*** (error happening here)

  while(tokPtr != NULL)
  {
        tokPtr = strtok(NULL, "|");
        eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str = tokPtr;
        //printf("%s\n", eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str);      

        xIndex++;
  } 
}
```

Been stuck on this for a while any/all input appreciated and encouraged.

Comment: What is `Entry`? How is `eTable` defined? I hope you know, that `strtok` uses a static variable inside, so every time you call strtok, the previous return value will be vanished.

Comment: `typedef struct Entry 
{
        char *str;
        int iVal;
} Entry;`

Comment: `Entry eTable[x][y];`

Comment: @Koshinae I am aware of the static variable used within strtok but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: For starter, compile it with debug symbols and run it through a debugger. Then you can check what is it referring to, that causes to set off a sigsegv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the return value of the first `strtok()` call.

Also, in your `while` loop you check whether `tokPtr` is NULL, but then update it in the first line of the loop body before using it.

You need remove the initial set of `eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str`, and move the second `strtok()` call to the end of the `while` loop:

```
  tokPtr = strtok(currentLineStr, "|");

  while(tokPtr != NULL)
  {
        eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str = tokPtr;
        //printf("%s\n", eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str);      

        tokPtr = strtok(NULL, "|");
        xIndex++;
  }
```

Comment: I've tested out the changes you suggested but am still getting a segfault at the first(now only) assignment of `tokPtr` to `eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str`. appreciate any general direction you could direct me towards in terms of zeroing in on the problem.

Comment: There's more going on here than we can see from what you've posted.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't post enough context didn't want to just post a bunch of code and make anyone who wanted to help wade through it all to find stuff. Anything in particular that i could post that you think could be useful or should I post everything?

Comment: Start with what you have and trim it down as much as possible while still exhibiting the error condition.  Then post that.

Comment: so I never really figured out exactly what was going wrong, it just magically started working again while i was pairing things back as you suggested. So thanks for that.